# If an array isn't empty, can I safely assume it has a .last?

Tags: swift

I have an array of items and I'm trying to get the last item. The array is coming from SwiftData so it may be empty.

Q: Can I safely assume (thus force unwrap) `.last` if the array isn't empty?

```swift
if myArray.isEmpty {
  print("some error")
} else {
  print("\(myArray.last!) is definitely there")
}
```

Comment: Sure, but why not invert the `if` and unwrap `last`? `if let last = myArray.last { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

yes, but you could also unwrap it via

```
if let lastElement = myArray.last {
    print(lastElement)
} else {
    print("array is empty")
}
```

or use a `guard let` statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's technically safe (apart from multi-threaded access, which shouldn't be done to an `Array` anyway), but it would be bad practice. The beauty of optionals and Swift's conditional-binding syntax is that it combines this "check, then act" pattern into a single construct:

```swift
if let lastElement = myArray.last {
  print("\(lastElement) is definitely there")
} else {
  print("some error")
}
```